# Gathering multiple results in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Table: book  ║ Column info ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ - id         ║ int, pk     ║
║ - title (128)║ varchar     ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╝

╔══════════════╦═════════════╗
║Table: author ║ Column info ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ - id         ║ int, pk     ║
║ - name (128) ║ varchar     ║
║ - bookId     ║ int, fk     ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

*(I do realize that this is not a fully normalized example, trying to keep it simple.)*

Gathering data from them is pretty straight-forward:

```
SELECT b.title, a.name FROM book b
INNER JOIN author a ON a.bookId = b.id
WHERE b.id = x
```

However, this obviously yields one row per author - which is is not what I want.
Instead, I'm trying to fulfill this data-structure:

> [ String title, String[] authors (array) ]

**Is it possible to do this in one single query?** Preferably without "merging" the author columns into one single string. Something like an internal array in the column itself.

Comment: You're looking for `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: "Internal array" in what context? GROUP_CONCAT will produce a string containing the concatenated values.  What language are you working in and how do you plan to manipulate the "internal array"?

Comment: @njk I believe that it'll join the columns in to one string? Not really what I am looking for.

Comment: @JimGarrison Java. I do realize that this can be done quite easily with one query, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: @pst Yeah, that's what I thought as well. It'd be quite handy, since it'd remove the need to do: `book = getBookData(id); book[authors] = getBookAuthors(id);` (just an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in one single query? Preferably without "merging" the author columns into one single string. Something like an internal array in the column itself.

**No :)**

GROUP_CONCAT and similar yields a scalar (String) result. There is *no* "Array of Strings" data-type in [standard] SQL.

This is *"OK"* because

1. a client program can de-normalize the data itself<sup>1</sup> for further processing, or
2. a de-normalized string can be sent to a command-line/text client for data visualization, or
3. the normalized form is desired for using the result with further queries<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Creating an Array for further processing is generally done on the client and varies by languages - it is a trivial one-liner in C#/LINQ.

<sup>2</sup> By leaving it in normalized form, further [Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) operations/optimizations can be applied. De-normalizing the data early can eliminate a wide range of valid (and possibly more efficient) query plans.

Answer (score 1):

You want `group_concat`:

```
select b.title,
       group_concat(a.name)
from book b join
     author a
     on b.id = a.bookid
group by b.id, b.title
```

This puts all the authors into a comma separated list.  You can specify the separator using the `SEPARATOR` statement.

Note I also grouped by the book id, in case two books have the same title.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT b.title,a.name, concat('[',b.title,',',a.name, ']') as output
 FROM book b 
 INNER JOIN author a
 ON b.id = a.bookid
 GROUP BY b.id, b.title
```

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1acbb/2)